# Need help to increase/decrease amount through checkbox when I select/deselect. Input type is number

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, shopping-cart

When the checkbox is selected then total amount should be increased according to the number of books in number field and when decreasing the number in number field the total should decrease and if the checkbox is deselected then also the total amount should decrease. Click here to see website
http://www.eduvision.edu.pk/guide.php

> Here is my code which I applied.

```
$(function(){
  var totalAmount = 0;
  $('input[id="total"]').change(function(){
    //get last span which is just before the br element and read its text.
    var $priceSpan = $(this).nextUntil('br').last();
    var amount = parseInt($priceSpan.text()) * (parseInt($priceSpan.prev('span').find('input').val()) || 1);

    //if checked then add amount otherwise substract it.
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
     {
       totalAmount += amount;
     }
     else
      {
        totalAmount -= amount;
      }
    //show total amount in amount span
    $('#amount').html(totalAmount);
  });
});
```

Comment: is your input a checkbox or a type number?

Comment: HTML would help. Change `$('input[id="total"])` to `$('input#total')` or just `$('#total')`

Comment: my input is checkbox and aslo number .... number is used to increase the number of books when it is increase or decrease that will effect the total amount but right now when checkbox is in checked state and you increase the number i wont add up to total @madalinivascu

Comment: how can a input be to things at the same time? enlighten me

Comment: provide html of the js code

Comment: @madalinivascu i have given the link you can check that